# How can I stop two threads colliding when accessing java ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have two threads which both need to access an `ArrayList<short[]>` instance variable.

One thread is going to asynchronously add `short[]` items to the list via a callback when new data has arrived : `void dataChanged(short[] theData)`

The other thread is going to periodically check if the list has items and if it does it is going to iterate over all the items, process them, and remove them from the array.

How can I set this up to guard for collisions between the two threads?

This contrived code example currently throws a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
//instance vairbales
private ArrayList<short[]> list = new ArrayList<short[]>();

//asynchronous callback happening on the thread that adds the data to the list
void dataChanged(short[] theData) {
    list.add(theData);
}

//thread that iterates over the list and processes the current data it contains
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            for(short[] item : list) {
                //process the data 
            }

            //clear the list to discared of data which has been processed. 
            list.clear(); 

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the type of list to a [thread safe list implementation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

```
private List<short[]> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<short[]>();
```

Note that this type of list is not extremely efficient if you mutate it a lot (add/remove) - but if it works for you that's a simple solution.

If you need more efficiency, you can use a [synchronized list](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) instead:

```
private List<short[]> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<short[]>());
```

But you will need to synchronize for iterating:

```
synchronized(list) {
    for(short[] item : list) {
        //process the data 
    }
}
```

EDIT: proposals to use a `BlockingQueue` are probably better but would need more changes in your code.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to use a [producer consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) queue like an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) instead or a similar concurrent collection.

> The producer–consumer problem (also known as the bounded-buffer problem) is a classic example of a multi-process synchronization problem. The problem describes two processes, the producer and the consumer, who share a common, fixed-size buffer used as a queue. The producer's job is to generate a piece of data, put it into the buffer and start again. At the same time, the consumer is consuming the data (i.e., removing it from the buffer) one piece at a time. The problem is to make sure that the producer won't try to add data into the buffer if it's full and that the consumer won't try to remove data from an empty buffer.

One thread [`offer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29)s `short[]`s and the other [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)s them.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into a [blockingqueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for this instead of an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java's synchronization support.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) covers making a group of statements synchronized on a specified object. That is: only one thread may execute any sections synchronized on that object at once, all others have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `synchronized` blocks, but I think the best solution is to not share mutable data between threads at all.

Make each thread to write in its own space and collect and aggregate the results when the workers are finished.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

You can ask the Collections class to wrap up your current ArrayList in a synchronized list.